# How to ignore empty columns in .csv file when using readline() in a four loop with Python?

Tags: python, list, file, iteration

I've seen similar questions for other languages but in Python I didn't see. Basically I have a function that loops through reading lines in a .csv file to get the data into a list of lists. It splits at each column which is read as a comma.

My question is there are two empty columns in the file, my question is how can I make my for loop ignore the empty columns or alternatively how do I strip/remove out empty lists?

this is my current function to read from the file.

```
    def read_file_lines(my_file):
"""This function will read user file to list"""
my_list = []
for line in my_file:
    line = my_file.readline()
    my_list.append(line)
return my_list

output:
['AAPL', '2/6/12', '58.064457', '', '']
['AAPL', '9/1/15', '100.91523', '', '']
['AAPL', '5/12/09', '15.570792', '', '']
['MSFT', '5/15/17', '65.6707', '', '']
['MSFT', '6/21/10', '20.752356', '', '']
['AAPL', '2/14/18', '164.227203', '', '']
['IBM', '12/26/17', '142.835663', '', '']
['AAPL', '4/17/09', '15.445643', '', '']
['MSFT', '4/2/09', '15.037685', '', '']
['IBM', '8/3/18', '140.947739', '', '']
['AAPL', '9/21/09', '23.029552', '', '']
```

Comment: line.split(",")[:-2]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a CSV parser, such as the one included in the Python standard library - docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Once you load a particular row you can manipulate it as you would any other Python list:

```
import csv

list = []
for row in csv.reader(my_file):
   row = row[:-2]  # remove last two columns
   my_list.append(row)
```